# how to know if the water valve connection is metal or plastic?

Tags: plumbing, dishwasher

I am buying a new dishwasher. The installation requires a metal connection to the existing water valve. How do i know if i have a metal or plastic connection?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You look at it, and feel it. That looks very much like a plastic valve, based on the color, the mold seals and the details molded into it.

Does it look like plastic, or does it look like metal?

Comment: Yep, and metal is rarely painted from the factory for this application. It's usually chromed brass.

Comment: And if it is painted, the mold lines will appear rounded, as the paint covers them partially. The part has quite clear mold lines, indicating it's not painted. So that part is plastic.

Answer (score 0):

That is plastic alright. It is called polybutylene. If you are going to abide by the DW Mfg directive then you will have to convert the Polybutylene to copper. The big box stores have these fittings.  Also a Plumbing wholesaler may have it.  The mobile home repair houses have these fittings also.  My Recommend is convert the ply-B to a male hose thread.